# Regional word for paperboard that school children use in projects?

Tags: single-word-requests, dialects

I'm talking about large paperboard that school children create their projects on. They might draw or paste things on them, usually to present some sort of information. You may see them carrying them rolled up and held with a rubber band.

[image: School project on paperboard]
*[M's global warming poster presentation](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ttcopley/4644205614/) by [ttcopley](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ttcopley/).*

What is this called in the New York region?

Comment: Probably called that elsewhere in the US. Maybe Rhode Island.

Comment: I know I call it a manila cardboard.

Comment: I think I call it 'Bristol board,' or is that the thinner stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be called [poster board](http://www.staples.com/Poster-Boards/cat_CL140932). It may also be called a [tri-fold display board](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00753IXV8).